# Remove adjacent duplicated words from string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, deduplication

I have a string like this string:

```
one one tow tow three three tow one three
```

How can i remove duplicated words to make it like this:

```
one tow three tow one three
```

The point is that I want to write a script that remove duplicated words if they are adjacent only

I have tried:

```
echo "$string" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) printf("%s%s",$i,FS)}{printf("\n")}'
```

but it removes non-adjacent duplicated words also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "one one tow tow three three tow one three" | tr " " "\n" | uniq | tr "\n" " "
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `\s` shorthand:

```
$ echo 'one one tow tow three three tow one three' |
awk -v RS='\\s+' '
    $0 != prev { out = (NR>1 ? out OFS : "") $0; prev = $0 }
    END { print out }
'
one tow three tow one three
```

or, still GNU awk but inspired by [@nezabudka's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/667907/133219) but with a couple of fixes to ensure it'll work no matter what sequences of spaces separate the input fields, and no matter which characters the input fields contain, and to ensure the output ends in `\n` so it's a valid POSIX text file:

```
$ echo one one tow tow three three tow one three |
awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]+' '
    $1 != prev { out = out $1 RT; prev=$1 }
    END { print out }
'
one tow three tow one three
```

otherwise with any awk:

```
$ echo 'one one tow tow three three tow one three' |
awk '{
    out = $1
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( $i != $(i-1) ) {
            out = out OFS $i
        }
    }
    print out
}'
one tow three tow one three
```

Answer (score 5):

If the line is not more than 2500(example 1000) columns:

```
echo one one tow tow three three tow one three |
    fmt -1 | uniq | fmt -1000
```

GNU awk:

```
echo one one tow tow three three tow one three |
    awk -v RS=' ' '$1 != D {printf "%s", $1 (RT?RS:ORS); D=$1}'
```

Updated(If you are sure that the line ends with a line feed):

```
echo one one tow tow three three tow one three |
    awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '$1 != D {printf "%s", $1 RT; D=$1}'
```

Otherwise(universal way):

```
echo -n one one tow tow three three tow one three |
    awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '$1 != D {printf "%s", $1 (RT?RT:ORS); D=$1}'
```

Explanation:
The GNU version has a built-in variable RT which is assigned a real value corresponding to the template from the RS. For example, if a template `[[:space:]]` is defined to the RS variable, then the RT variable will be dynamically assigned a character terminating the record in each case - whitespace or tabulation or line feed.
If the RS variable is assigned a character class template `RS=[[:space:]]` then the ternary operator should be changed to `(RT?RT:ORS)` or just `RT`

Comment: +1: solution is particularly elegant and easy to read. Incidentally I had never come across `RT` before and so, because my Gawk 5.1.0 man page produced zero result (o_0), I had to check https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/awk-split-records.html to fully understand the magic of its use in the ternary operator `(RT?RS:ORS)`. The trick may be common, but perhaps a bit of explaining on `RT` would further enlighten the masses... ;-)

Comment: @Cbhihe, just added

Answer (score 4):

You could use `uniq` after having put all the words on different lines:

```
string='one one tow tow three three tow one three'
printf '%s\n' "${string// /
}" | uniq | paste -sd ' ' -
```

Or with `perl`, allowing more than just one space character to delimit the words and preserving the spacing between groups of duplicates:

```
string='  one one tow   tow  three three tow one three '
perl -le 'print s/(?<!\S)(\S+)(\s+\1)+(?!\S)/\1/gr for @ARGV' -- "$string"
```

gives:

```
  one tow  three tow one three
```

Same with ksh93's `${var//pattern/replacement}` parameter expansion operator (which some other shells, including bash copied, but not the more advanced pattern matching operators):

```
$ string='  one one tow   tow  three three tow one three '
$ print -r - "${string//~(<!\S)+(\S)+(+(\s)\1)~(!\S)/\1}"
  one tow  three tow one three
```

Or with `zsh` (another shell will perl-like pattern matching operator support), modifying the variable in place:

```
$ string='  one one tow   tow  three three tow one three '
$ autoload regexp-replace
$ set -o rematchpcre
$ regexp-replace string '(?<!\S)(\S+)(\s+\1)+(?!\S)' '$match[1]'
$ print -r - "$string"
  one tow  three tow one three
```

Or `fish`:

```
$ set string '  one one tow   tow  three three tow one three '
$ string replace -a --regex '(?<!\S)(\S+)(\s+\1)+(?!\S)' '$1' $string
  one tow  three tow one three
```

If words like in your example are all made of alnums (or underscores), you can take a similar approach with the busybox implementation of `awk` where the negative look-around perl operators can be replaced replaced with the `\<` and `\>` word boundary operators (similar to perl's `\b`, so would be more like `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` as perl look-around operators):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$string" | busybox awk '{print gensub("\\<(\\S+)(\\s+\\1)+\\>", "\\1", "g")}'
  one tow  three tow one three
```

You can't use that approach if your words contain characters other than alnums or underscore as for instance it would change `one-two two three` to `one-two three` as there is a word boundary in-between `-` and `two`.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to use sed (GNU for `+` and `\<`) and using `-E` syntax to make the regex simpler.

This regex removes one duplicated word (of two accepted):

```
$ string='one one tow tow three three tow one three'
$ echo "$string" |
    sed -E 's/(\<([^ ]+)[ ]+)\2/\1/g' 

one  tow  three  tow one three
```

But we can extend the idea to remove any amount of repetitions

```
$ string='one one tow   tow     tow     tow three three tow one one onebook one three three'

$ echo "$string" | 
    sed -E 's/(\<([^ ]+)[ ]+)(\2([ ]+|$))+/\1/g'

one tow   three tow none one onebook three
```

Or a slightly more complex BRE regex (which accepts space and tab):

```
$ echo "$string" | 
    sed  's/\(\<\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\(\2\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}\|$\)\)\{1,\}/\1/g'

one tow   three tow none one onebook three
```

Note: As sed is a line oriented tool, this will work only in one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Use perl.  e.g. The following gets rid of adjacent repeated words even across line-boundaries (using perl's `-0777` option to slurp the entire input at once):

```
$ printf 'one one two\n two two\ntwo three three two\none\nthree\nthree\n' |
    perl -0777 -p -e 's/\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+\b/$1/g'
one two three two
one
three
```

The `\1` in the left-hand-side (LHS) of the `s/search (LHS)/replace (RHS)/` operation is a back-reference to the previously matched pattern group `(\w+)`.  `$1` is the same capture group on the replace or right-hand-side of the operation.

BTW, without piping it into perl, the input looks like this, with duplicate adjacent words across multiple lines:

```
$ printf 'one one two\n two two\ntwo three three two\none\nthree\nthree\n' 
one one two
 two two
two three three two
one
three
three
```

Notes:

1. `\b` is an anchor like `^` or `$` but instead of matching the beginning or end of a line, it matches the (zero-width) boundary between words
2. `\w` matches any word character, which is defined in the `perlre` man page as:

> \w [3]  Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus
> other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks)
>
> ...
>
> [3] See "Unicode Character Properties" in perlunicode for details

If you want to strictly match alpha (i.e. letter) characters only (without digits or underscores), you could use `[[:alpha:]]+` instead of `\w+`.

3. If your input text might contain unicode characters, there are several ways of dealing with that but the simplest is to just use perl's `-C` option:

```
$ echo 'öne öne öne two öne one' |
    perl -C -0777 -p -e 's/\b([[:alpha:]]+)(?:\s+\1)+\b/$1/g'
öne two öne one
```

See `man perlrun` and search for `-C` for details on this option.  If you're really interested in the topic, see also the man pages for `perlunicode`, `perlunitut`, `perluniintro`, and `perlunifaq`. As you might guess from the amount of documentation, dealing with unicode is simple and straight-forward for the most part, but can be fairly complex and subtly nuanced in various situations.